# Error code when using gather environment

Tags: equations, align, gather

So I have this simple code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

Given perfect data we can use Bayesian inference to infer our rate constants. This allows us to know the state of the system at given times, this is called our sample path denoted as;
\begin{gather*}
 $\mathbf x = \{ x(t) : t \in [0,T]\}$
\end{gather*}
Complete information on the sample path means that we what time of reaction occurs at different times\\
The form of the Gillespie algorithm means the likelihood function is constructed as
\begin{gather*}
$L(c;\mathbf x)$ = $\{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n h_{v_i}(x(t_{i_1},c_{v_i}\}$exp$$\{-\int_0^Th_0(x(t),c)dt\}$$
\end{gather*}
\\
A critical observation is that our rate laws can be written in the form, 
\begin{align*}
$h_j(x,c_j) = c_jg_j(x)$
\intertext{which leads to;}
$L_j(c_j;\mathbf{x}) = c_j^{r_j}exp\{-c_j\int_0^T g_j(x(t))dt\}$, $j=1,...,v$
\end{align*}\\
We assume we have independent gamma priors for our rate constants
\begin{gather*}
$c_j ~ Ga(a_j,b_j)$, $j=1,..,v$
\end{gather*}\\
Using Bayes Theorem we are able to produce a posterior for our rate constants,
\begin{gather*}
$c_j|\mathbf {x}$ ~ $Ga(a_j+r_j,b_j+\int_0^Tg_j(x(t))dt)$, $j=1,...,v$
\end{gather*}\\
Applying this to our Michaelis-Menten model produces graphs of the prior and posterior seen below



\end{document}
```

but I keep getting the error

```
Missing { inserted. <to be read again>}
```

But I dont understand what this means

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of `$` and `$$` within `gather` and `align` environments, but you don't have to use them because you are already in math mode within those environments.

Moreover, don't use `\\` in normal text only to go to a new line, just leave an empty line to create a new paragraph or use `\newline`.

There is a command for "exp": `\exp` and for ":": `\colon`, and with `\quad` you can leave some space. Little things like those excluded, I haven't corrected your formulas, but there are other errors, I'm sure some mathematicians here will be happy to improve them.

Moreover, as David pointed out in his comment, it's better to use `\[...\]` than `gather` for one line equations.

Eventually, as egreg said, there is no need to use `\intertext` inside `gather`, and use `\dots` instead of `...`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Given perfect data we can use Bayesian inference to infer our rate constants. This allows us to know the state of the system at given times, this is called our sample path denoted as:
\[
 \mathbf{x} = \{ x(t)\colon t \in [0,T]\}
\]
Complete information on the sample path means that we what time of reaction occurs at different times\newline
The form of the Gillespie algorithm means the likelihood function is constructed as
\[
L(c;\mathbf{x}) = \bigl\{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n h_{v_i}(x(t_{i_1},c_{v_i}\}\exp\{-\int_0^Th_0(x(t),c)dt\bigr\}
\]
A critical observation is that our rate laws can be written in the form, 
\[
h_j(x,c_j) = c_jg_j(x)
\]
which leads to:
\[
L_j(c_j;\mathbf{x}) = c_j^{r_j}\exp\{-c_j\int_0^T g_j(x(t))dt\}, \quad j=1,\dots,v
\]
We assume we have independent gamma priors for our rate constants
\[
c_j ~ Ga(a_j,b_j), \quad j=1, \dots ,v
\]
Using Bayes Theorem we are able to produce a posterior for our rate constants,
\[
c_j|\mathbf {x} ~ Ga(a_j+r_j,b_j+\int_0^Tg_j(x(t))dt), \quad j=1,\dots,v
\]
Applying this to our Michaelis-Menten model produces graphs of the prior and posterior seen below
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it's better to use `\[` than `gather` for one line equations (see the last one where `\[` would use `\shortdisplayskip`)

Comment: Also, there's no reason for `\intertext` inside `gather`.

Comment: @CarLaTeX And `\dots` instead of `...` `;-)`

Comment: `j=1,\dots,v` is the right code